# pre honeycomb fragment android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-3.0-honeycomb, fragment

In previous version say version 11 examples(by google) inits the fragments in an layout and
hides and shows them.
The compatibility example on the other hand literally creates the fragments with a constructor.

1) Regular fragments :

Fragment fragment = (MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);

2) The Compatibility package examples :

Fragment fragment = new MyFragment(this);

IF I FOLLOW THE SECOND WAY it seems that the activity cycle goes crazy.

For instance , getActivity() returns null in the fragment.

And There are few other issues.

Which is the right way to do it yet supporting compatibility package?

Comment: Can you include a code example for how you create the Fragment via the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the second way you are just creating an instance of the class that is not attached to any activity.
After doing that you need to add it dynamically either by using add or replace.

The first option works if you have embedded the fragment in the xml file that your activity uses to inflate its view